# Understanding the problem statement

Tags: design-process

I have given the following problem statement to come up with a solution. The solution must be a short format communication platform meant for workplaces (TikTok/Instagram Stories). However, I struggle to understand the approach. I have been doing a competitor analysis but couldn't find any similar competitors. Appreciate it if any of you can provide ideas or a couple of low fidelity ideas to get started.

[image]

Comment: Yikes. Imagine a workplace where the communication took place on an Instagram-style feed. Don't forget the algorithm that shows them only what you think they'll like.

Answer (score 1):

I think the brief you have been given is rather poor.
For once, the problem statement does not state a problem, but proposes a solution. Then we have two problems in the context

1. workplace communication is boring and superfluous (esp. during remote meetings)
2. People need to write long messages to get their ideas across

IMO, these are different problems. If your assignment is to follow the design process, then I would challenge the brief and ask why it needs to be tiktok for business. If your assignment is to just "UI Design an app", then I would just copy TikTok/Instagram UI and sprinkle a bit of business context on it (e.g. departments, send to coworkers, coffee corner, office pets).